# Google грозит закрыть мой аккаунт разработчика Google Play за неактивность

Tags: android, google-play, mobile-development, app

Меньше года назад я зарегистрировал аккаунт разработчика Google Play и всё это время занимался web-версией своего приложения. Я не думал что они будут удалять мой аккаунт за неактивность, но недавно мне пришло письмо:

> Your Google Play Developer account is at risk of being closed because it is not being used. Google Play Developer accounts are intended for active developers who publish and actively maintain apps.
> If you intend to use your account, please follow these steps:
>
> 1. Sign in to your Play Console
> 2. Create and set up your app
> 3. If you’re not ready to make your app public, you can use Internal app sharing, Internal testing, or Closed testing to safely upload without it being generally available.

Вопросы:

1. Google требует с меня уже готовый прототип приложения, предназначенный для тестирования? Я не смогу отделаться от них чем-то простым вроде приложения, выводящего: "Hello, world!"?
2. Как мне сделать приложение которое устраивало бы Google (чтобы они не закрыли мой аккаунт) за 1-2 дня, чтобы не забрасывать web-разработку, которой я сейчас активно занят? В ближайшем будущем я хочу сделать гибридное мобильное приложение (на основе web-версии), но я не могу сейчас бросить web-разработку и начать учить фреймворк для создания мобильных приложений. Спасибо.

Comment: Как мне сделать приложение которое устраивало бы Google (чтобы они не закрыли мой аккаунт) за 1-2 дня, чтобы не забрасывать web-разработку, которой я сейчас активно занят? - какой ответ вы здесь хотите услышать?) вам же вроде написали что можно просто создать приложение, это не значит что вы будете что-то программировать, просто у вас будет активность в акк и всё, ничего публиковать мне кажется не нужно будет, но я могу ошибаться, если что меня поправят

Comment: @Andrew Может быть Google регулярно шлёт вам такие письма и у вас уже есть готовый алгоритм что именно надо делать.

Comment: Что вы потеряете, если аккаунт удалят? Я этого момента не понял. Ну удалят и удалят. Пусть так оно и будет, потом просто при необходимости можно будет снова создать новый аккаунт на те же данные. Раз там нет ни приложения, ни аналитики, ни, тем более, финансов.

Comment: @МихаилИсаев Аккаунт разработчика Google Play привязан к моему основному Google-аккаунту. Они закрывают аккаунт разработчика Google Play без возможности его восстановления (https://youtu.be/FhtKIZPfZMs?t=545). Я не знаю смогу ли я потом создать аккаунт разработчика Google Play через свой основной Google-аккаунт.

Comment: Да и платить же вроде надо за эккаунт разработчика? Деньги пропадут, жалко. )  А так насколько я понял да, можно hello world написать, главное что-то сделать вообще в эккаунте.

Comment: Никогда не привязывайте акк разработчика к реальным активным аккаунтам! По вашему вопросу - можно создать любое приложение для внутреннего тестирования чтобы сделать имитацию живого акк разработчика

Comment: @AndreyMihalev Почему вы считаете что аккаунт разработчника нельзя привязывать к основному аккаунту?

Comment: В видео по ссылке женщина говорит: "вы всегда сможете создать новый аккаунт, но старый вернуть не получится". То есть создать новый аккаунт получится всегда. И я вот понять не могу, зачем вообще нужно было его создавать, если разработка началась с веба? В чём суть действий? Я веду разработку мобильной игры и до финансирования не собираюсь ничего регистрировать, ведь для тестирования/демо хватает билдов на устройства.

Comment: @МихаилИсаев Я не хочу создавать ещё один Google-аккаунт если я не смогу привязать новый аккаунтр разработчика к моему основному Google-аккаунту. Аккаунт нужен был, т.к. перед началом web-разработки я изучал возможности гибридных мобильных приложений. У меня один и тот же код используется для сайта, мобильной версии сайта и для двух мобильных приложений.

Comment: Новый аккаунт будет привязан к основному Google-аккаунт (это стандартная парадигма, что аккаунт разработчика создаётся от основного аккаунта).

Answer (score 2):

Выложите любое приложение типа *Hello world*. Потом его можно удалить.

Например, которое выводит поочередно красный, жёлтый, зелёный и белый экран, дайте название "тест экрана" или как-то так.

Причем необязательно его выкладывать во всеобщий доступ, достаточно закрытого тестирования.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]