# Блокировка аккаунта в аккаунт разработчика в Google Play Console(App Bundle, формать .aab)

Tags: android, google-play-console

Прислали мне письмо:

> Этот аккаунт разработчика может быть удален из-за отсутствия активности
> Чтобы сохранить этот аккаунт, загрузите набор App Bundle в любую версию до 13 окт. 2021 г.. Если вы этого не сделаете, аккаунт будет удален навсегда. Регистрационный взнос возвращен не будет.

Отвечал им: "у меня нет сейчас возможности сейчас сделать в виде App Bundle, но аккаунт мне нужен в этом году." Но этого ничего не дало.

Скиньте, пожалуйста, любой файл с форматом .aab, чтобы я мог показать активность.
Не могу найти, чтобы скачать

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Google грозит закрыть мой аккаунт разработчика Google Play за неактивность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1318533/google-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%bd%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-google-play-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: Да только его закрыли, а ссылку на файл.aab никто не дал. Не готов на данный момент разбираться, как его создать